# Displaying text and image (RTF) data in WPF & Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, richtextbox, rtf

In our app (Silverlight 5 and WPF) we are looking to put in a help section.  The help section will contain simple text and images so thought RTF would be perfect for this.  On closer inspection it seems Silverlight doesnt support RTF documents.

What other method could we use to display formatted text / images in both Silverlight and WPF that would allow the content to be generated by a supports person (i.e. no coding knowledge required)

Comment: FlowDocument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx

Comment: FlowDocument doesnt exist in silverlight